# USB-C to HDMI (MacBook Pro 116inch 2019)

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt, hdmi

I bought a new [Belkin USB-C to HDMI](https://www.apple.com/ie/shop/product/HKQ22ZM/A/belkin-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter?fnode=33c43503ad8606f6ef8596727d5c9e195afcd0805ef930fdb1660693a9951b5498446b3bbdf4ede4b1f877c49be4a58524e61d6b1c4da39a0c84cbf594cd41f573d23ad86b6439c6c71cab87b84d5f5ed05f9186f54532ddbc9549f375dae95c) adaptor from the Apple Online Store.

The title is USB-C but the tech mention "Connections: HDMI, Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C)" so I assume it's Thunderbolt 3.

Anyway, it was working fine the first time I connected it (to a 5K ultra wild LG 49inch) but then after rebooting, nothing.

After unplugging and replugging the USB-C cable, I had this message:
[image: Notification Center alert] (same issue whatever port I'm using)

Edit: and now my USB-C to ethernet won't connect.

Edit 2: after reseting SMC/NVRAM, the eth is connecting again but same issue with HDMI

Edit 3: it won't connect with a thunderbolt cable (which works fine with the same display and my iMac.)

Device:
MacBookPro16,1
Processor Name: 8-Core Intel Core i9
AMD Radeon Pro 5500M
Intel UHD Graphics 630
Big Sur 11.3.1 (20E241)

Comment: The adaptor specs clearly indicate that 5K is not supported: **Supports up to 4k@60Hz (4096x2160) resolutions**. However, I think it should still work at a lower res, but I am not sure

Comment: right, how do I missed that... (weirdly I got it to work in 5K too the first time I connected.) I think I have a issue with my thunderbolt port too anyway as it'w won't work neither with a thunderbolt 3 cable. thank you anyway

Comment: The USB-C type ports on your Mac support USB, Thunderbolt 3 and DisplayPort devices. When you plug the *"Belkin USB-C to HDMI Adapter"* into the Mac, the port operates in [DisplayPort over USB-C mode (DP Alt mode)](https://www.displayport.org/displayport-over-usb-c/).